# Filling in Missing Data for Biological Experiment

Tags: regression, machine-learning, data-imputation, semi-supervised-learning

I am trying to implement a semi-supervised learning model with biological data. In my case, I'm using features from DNA. I have a number of experiments each with many observations. Each observation within an experiment represents an "event" happening in one experiment of a biological process. So, the labels are the frequency of this event happening within an experiment. Technically, all the frequency labels in one experiment constitute a distribution. So, the entire data set has many distributions of frequency values. I only have two features that I eventually hope to predict this frequency. However, some of the frequency values are missing within experiments while others are not.

Do you guys have any suggestions on semi-supervised learning models to help deal with this issue? I've looked at GANs, but it seems to me that these are primarily used for images and generating completely new training samples rather than inferring values when features and some of the labels within an experiment are already known.

An example of the data I am working with is:

```
Experiment#  | Attribute1  | Attribute2  | TargetAttribute
```

So now given a new set of observations with the same experiment #, I would like to fill in the missing values of TargetAttribute.

Comment: Have you viewed Attribute1, Attribute2, and TargetAttribute as a 3D scatterplot? That can sometimes give useful insight.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'm more looking into an ML model.  Right now I am looking into this tutorial: https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-missing-data-python/ but it does not seem to be working well, so I'm trying to find another